# JPanel repaint() call not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I feel as though the solution to this is very simple and I'm just overlooking something stupid, but I can't seem to make the repaint() method of one of my JPanels work. The JPanel in question is a member object of another class which handles all the logic behind what is drawn to the JPanel, however, whenever I call repaint() in my thread, I do not see anything drawn, nor do I see my System.out.println() call, which I put in there for debugging purposes. I have put the files on Github for convenience. Here are the three files I think MIGHT have something to do with it. You can always look at the others if you need to.

[SageLife.java](https://github.com/packetpirate/SageLife/blob/master/SageLife/src/sagelife/SageLife.java)

[LifeFramework.java](https://github.com/packetpirate/SageLife/blob/master/SageLife/src/sagelife/framework/LifeFramework.java)

[Grid.java](https://github.com/packetpirate/SageLife/blob/master/SageLife/src/sagelife/canvas/Grid.java)

I've created plenty of JPanels before and have rarely encountered this problem, so I'm just not sure what's causing it.

Comment: for better help sooenr post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about a.m. issue, reduce code, another issue is that link will be expired, not accesible for future readers,

Comment: I feel like I'm blind -- where is `initializeThread()` in `LifeFramework` being called?

Comment: Mama mia! Thats'a spaghetti code!

Comment: initializeThread() is called from the actionPerformed() method in Controls.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding `paintComponents` rather than `paintComponent` in your `Grid` `JPanel`. This does not follow Swing's paint chain mechanism.

```
@Override
public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
```

Note: always go for [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) over `Thread` for handling UI updates in Swing.

Comment: Shouldn't the @Override annotation warn of this on compile?

Comment: Nope, `paintComponents` exists also but is the wrong method for custom painting :)

Comment: Actually, startThread() is called, in Controls.java. I know this because I inserted System.out.println() calls to show me when it starts, stops, and a call for each tick of the thread. The thread runs... repaint() just doesn't work.

I have confused paintComponents() with paintComponent() in the past.